# Ignite Websession persistance issue with HttpServletResponse.encodeURL

Tags: weblogic, ignite

Using Apache Ignite Websession Persistence with Weblogic. The HttpServletResponse.encodeURL method does not work as expected. The issue I'm facing are as follows when cookies are disabled from the browser.

1) Request is sent to node-1 and Ignite creates a new session and when you call HttpServletResponse.encodeURL it appends the 'jsessionId' to the URL and is fine.

2) When you hit the node-2 with the encoded URL from node-1, Ignite is able to pull the session from the Ignite Cache and doesn't create a new session, but when you call encodeURL it doesn't append the 'jsessionid'. This is because the response object has a reference to the Weblogic's HTTPRequest/session objects and not the Ignite wrapper HTTPServleteRequestObjects and it doesn't append the sessionId to the URL.

The only way I can workaround this issue is to override the implementation of encodeURL and encodeRedirectURL methods which I don't prefer as it could be error prone.

Has anybody else faced this issue and found a good solution ?

Comment: Could you please attach a reproducer?

Comment: I would suggest sending this question to the Ignite user mailing list with a small reproducer, so the community could see what the issue is - https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html#mail-lists